# How to find the IP of a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do I find the IPv4 address of a Minecraft server (e.g `us.mineplex.com`, `mc.hypixel.net`)?

I need to do this because I am testing something for my own server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple! Just open up a command line/terminal window (doesn't matter what operating system) and type:

```
ping <your server address here>
```

That should work!

Comment: It might be worth adding that `ping` will output a bunch of stuff, including the IP of your server (it'll look like `(your server address here) [(the IP)]`).

Answer (score 44):

Another alternative is to use `nslookup` which queries the name directly from DNS:

```
C:\> nslookup google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2601:647:4a03:6e2b:9610:3eff:fe0e:6c13

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4005:801::200e
          216.58.194.174
```

This shows the IPV6 address followed by the IPV4.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not the one using `ping`. For obvious reasons ...

Comment: @NumLock I doubt it's obvious for a significant portion of the userbase here. Feel free to elaborate.

Comment: @Mast seeing the IP from using ping is a side-effect of the command, whereas using getting the IP from nslookup is the intended purpose of the command.

Comment: @Spork Just to play devil's advocate on that point, more people are likely to have used/heard of `ping` than `nslookup`, and thus would be more likely to remember it next time they need it (rather than having to look it up again). So if they both do the job, it's useful that they're both presented. Ultimately though, I agree... `nslookup` is the canonical tool for the job.

Comment: Maybe more people know how to dig, so they will remember dig more easily than ping and nslookup. Dig is also shorter.

Comment: I kinda agree with @glibdud

Comment: Simply put, `ping` is the _wrong_ tool for the job. Period. Sure, it has that side effect, but the correct usage would be using `nslookup`. Simply because the tool is meant for exactly that: Get the IP from DNS by its name.

Comment: @NumLock To someone who's just trying to resolve an address, I don't think the design intent of the tool is relevant. Unless there are practical circumstances in which nslookup gives a correct resolution where ping doesn't, I have a hard time calling it a "wrong" tool for the job.

Comment: @glibdud To someone who's just trying to turn off his lights, I think just throwing a dripping wet sponge at your electrical outlet works. While you let the sponge soak up, have some [practical circumstances](http://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine).

Comment: @NumLock Terrible analogy, but good link.

Comment: @glibdud Terrible tool for DNS lookup, but good ICMP.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to the search bar beside your home button (bottom left hand corner) on your computer. Then type `cmd`.

[image]

After you open the command prompt type `ping mc.hypixel.net/serverip`.

Answer (score 0):

use

`ping -c 3 "server-address"`

on unix and unix-like systems(ctrl+t on most systems, and search for it in spotlight on a mac). and

`ping -n 3 "server-address"`

on windows in the command line(press windows key+r and type cmd, then type the command, `ping -n 3 server-address`)